# How can I choose what path node handle I am selecting?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to choose which path control handle you are selecting without first moving another handle out the way?

For example:

I have 3 points: **A**, **B**, and **C**.  I want to adjust the line between **A** and **B**.  To do that, I would adjust the control **AB**.  However, whenever I `edit` drag **B**, I adjust the control **BC**.  The only way that I know to adjust control **AB** is to move control **BC** out of the way, `edit` drag **B** again, and then move control **BC** back on top of **B**.

[image: Control Point Example]

Is there a way that I can choose which control I am moving while the control is still stacked on top of the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A far as my experiments go, Gimp always takes the "backwards" handle (except on "end" nodes, where it picks the "external" handle), so I do like you. However, I don't move the other handle back to the anchor when I am done, I just delete it (Ctr-Shift-Click) which is exactly the same thing.

Gimp's way sort of makes sense if you adjust the handles in the order in which you added the nodes: the first handle you need is the "backwards" one, and when you need to pick out the "forward" handle, the "backward" handle is in most case already out. Of course this assumes that you remember in which direction the stroke is going...

Comment: I had no idea you could delete handles.  Although not exactly intuitive, it solves the issue of being worried about moving the original handle back into the correct space.  Thanks.